# jQuery slider does not display

Tags: jquery, slider

so i figured i would start small...

no go.

the jquery UI slider does not display... what is wrong with this page?

http://www.bcidaho.com/healthcare-reform/timeline.asp

i have the jquery library called in the head, the UI core, and the UI slider js files...

my error is "object does not suppor this property or method"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including jQuery twice in the page, so it's erasing any plugins on the first instance.  You have this which is correct:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/js/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/js/ui.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But then later you have this again (line 47), which needs to be removed:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```